# NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm very new to java coding, and currently I'm developing an app for Android using Eclipse.

I am constantly getting a `NullPointerException` problem every time I run my java code, I'm guessing it's a simple problem, but I don't know how to resolve this error.

Here's the block of code that is relevant to this question:

```
EditText taskArray[] = new EditText[200];
String taskArr[] = new String[200];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    Button submit = new Button(this);
    submit.setText("enter dare");
    layout.addView(submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            inputdare();
        }
    });
}             

public void addtask()
{
    n++;
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    taskArray[n] = new EditText(this);
    layout.addView(taskArray[n]);
}

public void inputdare()
{
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
    }
}
```

so basically whenever I call the function `inputdare();`,

I would have the `NullPointerException` error, I'm really stuck and don't know what to do ):

also, the error message is here:

```
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.cep.daredevil.MainActivity.inputdare(MainActivity.java:135)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.cep.daredevil.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-08 09:50:36.273: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: .getText() always returns a string in the for loop? if it doesnt, the .toString() method is invoked on a null object.

Comment: Your TaskArray is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your inputdare()

```
public void inputdare()
{
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        if (taskArray[i].getText() != null) {
            taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void inputdare()
{
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
    }
}
```

In the above code you declare the taskArray, so when you retrieve from there it gives null to you. here for that case null.toString() gives exception.

use `taskArray[i].getText() != null` before
`taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();`

It's solve you  problem...

Answer (score 0):

Put a condition to prevent NullPointer Exception to debug it more

```
 public void inputdare()
  {
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
    if(taskArr[i]!=null)
    taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
    }
  }
```

You will get which array elements do have null values

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: if the taskArry[i] would be null, there would be no problem

Answer (score 0):

EditText taskArray[] = new EditText[200];

taskArray is an array and each of its individual are not initialized, so if you try to call a method on its member wihtout initializing it, they will generate a null pointer exception

So after decalring an array of Classes you will have to initialize individual objects

like

```
taskArray[0] = new EditText(context);
taskArray[1] = new EditText(context);
.
.
.
taskArray[200] = new EditText(context);
```

once you have made sure they are initialized then call the method inputDare(); This will solve the null pointer exception.

To exactly solve the probelm:

Now initialize all the EditText fields according to your requirement and add them up to your layout and then call the inputDare() method.

or you can also get the EditText Field objects by calling findViewByID()

IF n is initialized = 0 then n++ should come after the initialization of 
taskArray[n] = new EditText(this);

otherwise you will get an Nullpointer on the index 0 of the array

public void addtask()
{

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
taskArray[n] = new EditText(this);
layout.addView(taskArray[n]);
n++;
```

}

Comment: just a clarification what does 'context' mean?

Comment: that is just an example I have used normally when you initialize EditText Field you need the object of Context class. It depends how you want to initialize EditText field. Also look at my edit to the answer I have just figured out one more bug

Comment: @AnthonyWu Your null pointer is coming at element 0 of taskArray[n], it will be a good idea to put logging before taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString(); to print i and see where you get null pointer

Answer (score 0):

You did not called addTask() method anywhere in your code. So when you are clicking submit button and executing inputdere() method, your taskArray elements are null because

```
taskArray[n] = new EditText(this);
```

is not executed yet. So you are getting NullPointerException at

```
taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
```

To fix this issue add following code in you onCreate() method after adding button to you layout.

```
    n = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++) {
        addtask();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added your edittext to your layout put the call to addtask() inside onCreate()..